# Security of Fedora third party repo RPMFusion

Tags: fedora, security

Due to the nature of Fedora licensing, it does not come with many propeitary software like adobe, flash, and codecs. So many Fedora users resort to using RPMFusion. My question is how safe is RPMFusion from a security prespective and has it had any history of ever being 0wn3d? How much trust can I put on the rpm builders in RPMFusion?

I am aware every RPM package from RPMFusion is signed with their GPG keys and yum will verify (by default) the integrity of every package installed from RPMFusion.