# How to check the source code of an rpm fusion package?

Tags: fedora, rpm

This answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/617937/542871 mentions that one can check the code of an rpm fusion file at https://pkgs.rpmfusion.org/cgit/ but I did not find the file that I was interested in there. Are there other methods ?

Comment: What file/package are you looking for?  Your link should be the projects for all of the packages offered by RPMFusion.  To see the raw sources, there should be a link inside a project's `spec` file.

Comment: @GracefulRestart I am looking for the nvidia driver and cuda packages one usually installs with rpm fusion. That is, `akmod-nvidia` and `xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda`

Comment: If you run `dnf repoquery -l akmod-nvidia`, can you find the contents at https://pkgs.rpmfusion.org/cgit/  ?

Comment: It is a duplicate. The answer of Stephen mention Koji which answer your question. By browsing your package with Koji you can find and download the source package

Comment: @rickhg12hs thank you that helped to find the relevant files

Comment: @GAD3R Both with Koji and with the pkgs.rpmfusion.org/cgit site, searching directly for the package by the name used to install it did not provide the package when searching for `akmod-nvidia`. As mentioned in the answer by Voljtech Trefny , there is an extra step in finding the name of the soulrce package which might differ from the name of the installed package. I can try to add an edit to specify this difficulty in the title and in an edited paragraph

Answer (score 4):

You can browse https://rpmfusion.org/ , e.g.  Open: Fedora -> 39 -> Updates -> Free -> Source -> qmplay2 and then you'll see:

```
qmplay2-23.10.22-1.fc39.src [1.5 MiB]   Changelog by Martin Gansser (2023-10-23):

- Update to 23.10.22
```

The `src.rpm` **is** the source code. You can use e.g. rpm2cpio or Midnight Commander to extract/inspect it, however!

It's **not** a guarantee you can trust RPMFusion and I stopped doing so years ago. The problem is you have no control/insight into their build farm and thus binary packages may contain malware which is added during the build process.

---

Secondly when you install their repo file, you may download sources using this command: `dnf download --source package_name`, e.g. `dnf download --source cgit`.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to find out what is the name of the source package which can be different from the installed package name (usually because one source package provides multiple packages). For `xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda` its `xorg-x11-drv-nvidia`. You can get this information using `dnf repoquery --source xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda`.

Then you can find the package in [dist git](https://pkgs.rpmfusion.org/cgit/nonfree/xorg-x11-drv-nvidia.git/tree/), but the sources are not there, just the SPEC file (which may contain URL for downloading the sources, but it can be just a file name) and patches and other small files -- sources are usually too big to be included in the GIT repository. If you want to get the full source files, the easiest way is to download the SRPM (archive which contains SPEC and all sources) from [Koji](https://koji.rpmfusion.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=437) (pick the exact version you want to check and download the `.src.rpm` file in the *src* section) and extract it (SRPM is just an archive containing SPEC file and all sources).

If you want to play with the packaging a little bit more, you can install `rpmfusion-packager` and clone the entire dist git using `rfpkg clone xorg-x11-drv-nvidia` and then download the sources with `rfpkg sources`. You can read more packaging for RPMFusion [here](https://rpmfusion.org/Contributors).