# With Linux being open source what level of confidence is there that there are no back doors or Trojans in the code?

Tags: linux, malware

With Linux being millions of lines of code, with a huge number of device drivers, there are lots of places to hide trap doors and trojans.  Since it takes a long time to understand huge programs and latent defects are always present in software, I find it hard to believe that the NSA or FSB hasn't tried to introduce malware into Linux.  They are always looking for zero day exploits in Windows and iOS.   Since Linux runs on everything up to and including cruise missiles, this has to be an issue.

Comment: Have you checked the CSV databases for vulnerabilities in either the Linux kernel or in various libraries and applications? A continuous stream of patches are being produced. Linux is mostly open-source (with exceptions of, for example, nvidia drivers installed as blobs) but that does not make it any more bullet-proof than Windows or MacOS. For paranoia purposes, do you suppose that NSA/CIA/FSB couldn't introduce exploits into the MS code repository or the various chip factories in Indonesia?

Comment: Actually I have.  Re: your second question, I had worked for a very large consulting company and had a team a team on the ground in Shanghai deploying design tools for a certain Chinese company that is now on the U.S. blacklist.  The design data they were given still had the logos and copyright data of the U.S. firms in the data.  The data was obviously stolen.  I reported this to the Chairman's office and my entire team was taken off the project almost immediately.  So, yes, I am sure that exploits have been introduced into the code.  That's why this company is on  the blacklist.

Comment: Also see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/676944/367454

Comment: This question may be better placed at [Cybersecurity SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the attack you are talking about (**supply chain attack** on Open Source projects) is not only possible but regularly tried by malicious actors ([example](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/open-source-package-analysis-tool-finds-malicious-npm-pypi-packages/)).  However, given that the source code is public, malicious code is destined to be found eventually, especially for large projects. Compare this with closed source code, where you have no access to the source code and are forced to implicitly trust the vendor, and you'll realize that the Open Source model is, in general, more secure.

Answer (score -1):

This question, while interesting, contains some fairly common misconceptions and misunderstandings about 'Linux'. First, there is no such thing as a Linux Operating System. Linux is the kernel, and in this case, that distinction matters, a lot.

That kernel sees constant releases, either primary major version, or small patch version. Some vendors patch their repository kernels without changing their main version number, that's hard to do, and if I were concerned about security, I would not use that method, since then you are adding a second level of possible error, first, the original linux kernel version codebase, second, the patchset being applied to patching the stable kernel in the distro repositories.

So there's no such thing as 'linux', even when it comes to the Linux kernel, there are releases based on some commits made at some point. And those releases can be long term support, which means, currently, that Greg Kohn-Hartman patches those for their support lifetime to backport things like security fixes, or that the distribution has selected a kernel, frozen it, and is maintaining that branch, say, Redhat Corporation owned by IBM currently, which is a different entity in terms of their internal culture than when they were not owned by another company.

I wince any time I see someone ask about 'linux this or linux that', because there is no actual thing that corresponds to those words as a general thing, not in the sense of Windows 10, 11, or OSX version x or y, or Android version x or y, or iOS version x or y, which are largely known entities.

Assuming this question is for real, and the question of security is in fact truly foremost in the poster's mind, then we already know the following:

- You are not running Windows anywhere in your chain of access, including servers.
- You are not accessing anything with Android, via phone etc.
- You are using a fully sandboxed browser, if we are talking a desktop type situation, like Chromium, minus the google spyware.
- Objectively, if talking about a server, it does not have any gui stuff running, no desktops, window managers, nothing extra that could introduce extra security holes. If it does, security is clearly not a priority.
- The system being run is lean, and is running only what you have configured it to run, and does not contain any extra packages or services. In other words, it's not a default install of almost any distribution, except ones that allow base barebones installs, like Debian Net Install for example.

If all these apply, then we are probably looking at a fairly serious effort to do security, at which point, focusing on the Linux kernel security features begins to have a point, like properly configured SELinux, or whatever, well configured firewalls, if facing the internet, and so on.

But it's very important to be crystal clear on what the words mean before starting, for example, to ask if 'linux is secure', basically means nothing at all in this context, for example, say you are running a current kernel that gets updated at every new release, but you are running an Xorg desktop, with some insecure software that is not well written, and which can pop out of its cage via some standard hacker technique like a simple buffer overflow, then security is meaningless.

If SELinux, which I'm not personally familiar with, but I understand the basic ideas I think, is properly configured, that mitigates some attack vectors quite well from what I understand.

If on the other hand, you are in fact absolutely certain that security is truly your number one concern, then you'd be looking hard at OpenBSD, which is made by people who do not compromise at all when it comes to security, that's number one, everything else comes second. A nice OS by the way, very well designed.

Since that is very tightly controlled, and has very high coding standards, that are reviewed by people very skilled in the arts, and they do not allow random code or contributors in at all, that's your number one best bet for true real security. It's also got a much smaller attack surface, by design, and because it's not a huge project, but also because they will always dump code that is not maintained or debuggable rather than keep it to avoid inconveniencing some user or other. That's part of security truly coming first.

With any code base, you can introduce tricks, particularly if you split the tricks apart into apparently unrelated commits over time. I used that trick myself on an old project, not for evil ends, just because I didn't want users to know they could use it in a way that raised the risk of failure. That trick was never discovered by anyone, to this day. Very simple too, I used that method, splitting it apart in different commits, and locating the various bits of logic that made the trick work in apparently different places in the code.

But with this said, the guys who do linux are very good, they know what excellence looks like, they follow OpenBSD, and while they aren't willing to compromise things too much for corporate datacenter users, they are aware of these things, and actively patch and fix stuff all the time.

So if this isn't a strawman, we know you are not using OSX or Windows, aren't using Android, at least not for anything that can access or deal with the systems that are supposed to be secure. If that's not the case, then this is not a real question.

The very nature and essence of non free software is you can't see the source code, which means, you can't even ask this question about osx and windows, period. Also, windows suffered a huge data breach recently if my memory serves, and the codebase was exposed to the cracker underground for long enough for it to be grabbed many times over.

Somewhat to my surprise, the OpenBSD actually give the OSX kernel (the kernel, mind you, not osx desktop or programs, which can be anything), quite high marks when it comes to security and following good security practices. That however does not correspond to what I have seen personally when interacting with OSX, I've found it to be sloppy and very non robust system that is seriously lacking in many software areas, which does not fill me with any confidence about what lies under the covers. Not open source, so we can't check.

The more stuff running with or in the kernel (extra modules, drivers, you don't need, etc), the more stuff running over it, the more security holes.

When it comes to Linux kernels, BSD kernels, etc, I believe the layout is roughly sort of like this:

kernel > shell, tools, servers, process management etc. > display > desktops > desktop programs. Basically you can run a kernel running only servers, and a shell to interact with it, which would be the most secure.

Growing blobs like systemd are another question, which is highly relevant when you are talking about real security. That's somewhat difficult to track or understand fully, and I'd view that as a significant risk factor, since it I believe runs as PID 1, but essentially is doing too much. systemd however is not required to run linux, so it again comes down to security priorities, only running what you need, and knowing why each thing is installed that is running.

To put it another way, my workstation has a / partition that has I think about 30 GiB of data in it, of that, maybe 1 GiB is kernels, the rest is servers, programs, desktops, display managers, etc.

That's what most people are referring to when they use the term 'Linux', which is why that's not a very useful term.

However, I'd tend to trust the people working with the linux kernel over any closed source operating system, or operating system with large non free chunks and blobs, like the non free nvidia kernel driver blob, or even wifi blobs, aka 'firmware', which are likewise closed source by legal requirement, at least in USA.

But beyond any of this, if I want security as number one, I am running OpenBSD, period. Second, I'm running a barebones current kernel server running Linux and only the tools it needs, properly locked down and secured. Only OpenBSD is properly locked down and secured of all the operating systems I'm aware out of the box.

Comment: Many things to comment on here so I'll just touch on a few. `systemd` is not a blob - sources are available and well documented. New but I can't see that it is any worse than upstart or init systems. You also seem to swing between OpenBSD and a lean Linux kernel - can you point out why you're using both and when you choose one over the other? Last, I can't see any legal requirement in the US for nvidia, linksys, etc., to keep their drivers closed sourced.  This seems to be a commercial decision, now a legal one.

Comment: I was using the term "linux" as a shorthand way to refer to the kernel, the subcomponents and the device drivers... the roughly 20M lines of code that in aggregate comprise the open source operating system and its derivatives.  The question did lead me to a tool called Coverity that can perform a static analysis of software for common errors (e.g. buffer overflow) .  The tool produced estimated defect rates for all of the modules that comprise the thing called "linux".  That was a useful, albeit indirect, indirect measure of risk exposure in "linux".

Comment: I honestly think that the NSA'd have a greater national security risk if they willingly punched a hole into the very system that runs on all their servers and supercomputers(at least i think so?). So in the contrary, they'll probably also keep out that it stays clean. Stuff built on top would be a bit harder to control, so that's probably where the systemd-criticism came from. but even if you ignot

Comment: *But even then, that also counts for stuff like sudo or other utilities

Comment: "_The very nature and essence of non free software is you can't see the source code_" I'm not convinced that's a necessary cause and effect. "_can't_"? No. "_can't usually_"? Maybe. It's conceivable there could be a licence that allowed one to see code but neither share nor change it.

Comment: roalma, yes, I should have noted that. For example, Huawei offered full source code review to buyers of their 5g networking equipment to allay fears of chinese government back doors in the code. But it's not the norm. It's also worth noting that will come with an NDA, so even if there is some bad stuff in there, you could never expose it legally.

Comment: doneal24, systemd is generally referred to as a 'blob' because it's getting increasingly difficult to pull the various modules apart, making it increasingly more like the Windows 'hive' than a unix type tool. Re which to chose, I think it's just a matter of what is truly important: if security is absolute, then there's only OpenBSD, if you need some of the flexibility GNU/Linux platforms offer, but still want to retain security, a lean Linux is not a bad option. Nvidia can't open their blob probably for legal and competitive reasons, licensing issues. Wifi blob varies FCC I think is involved.

Comment: It's worth noting that vendors like Intel and Nvidia's idea of 'free software' is to move the code they don't want to, or can't, expose into the physical hardware, out of the kernel. That's what Nvidia is doing now with their allegedly coming 'open source drivers', they moved a lot of it into the graphics device, leaving only the kernel layer "open", which talks to the closed firmware blob. UEFI also is a very nice attack vector, given that it does too much, and is more like an operating system than a BIOS. Which is why CoreBoot exists. Very hard to avoid running blobs at some levels.

Comment: Leo S. my objection to systemd was based on direct experience of constant failures, which were exactly like windows failures, literally, reboot and pray, no other option. That happened to me many, many times. Could not do remote upgrades anymore for that reason. Not debuggable, too complicated, and not well written. Almost certainly an attack vector I'd guess. But linux doesn't need that, can use other init tools, which use a fraction of the code, sysvinit, runit, s6, finit, at least one of those will make it long term. After 10 years, I can usually now reboot after upgrade with systemd setup!